# In A-Frame, how do I give an entity a larger size for collision than its actual size? (using aabb-collider or another)

Tags: collision-detection, aframe, webvr

I have several a-frame entities for which I have collision detection working using Kevin Ngo's aabb-collider.  For some of them, I want to detect a "collision" using a bounding box larger than the bounding box based on the mesh. Can I do so using aabb-collider, or should I switch to Don McCurdy's sphere-collider instead?  If so, is there example code somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm rather using Don McCurdy's physics engine, but if You have to change Your whole concept it's easier to find a workaround. The [API](https://github.com/ngokevin/kframe/blob/master/components/aabb-collider/examples/basic/index.html) has no property which could change the collision box / object.

So how about making an invisible object, bigger than yours, and check the collision with it ?

```
<a-entity geometry="primitive:box" camera wasd-controls 
aabb-collider="objects: .collider" comp></a-entity>
<a-sphere scale="3 3 3" position="0 0 -5"  class="collider"    
material="color:green;opacity:0.1">
   <a-box color="blue"></a-box>
</a-sphere>
```

So, I have my camera, with a box geometry, so i can fly into the sphere,
The sphere has the corresponding collider class, and the box is the visible item.

Working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/9ofba5tv/2/). Check out the logs, it prints out the collision events.

Comment: That's an excellent idea.  I'm beginning to think that the answer to every problem while using A-Frame is to add another entity.

Comment: @DougReeder yes, and no :) While such workarounds can seem to help you with separating the visuals from the 'mechanics', it can easily get confusing and messy. I guess if You are consistent, it shouldn't be an issue. If You don't have further questions feel free to mark the anwser :)